# Why must angular momentum operator annihilate the vacuum?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, symmetry, vacuum

[image]

This is a sentence in the book, "An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory".

$J_z$is the z component of angular momentum.

Comment: Does the vacuum have a well defined angular momentum? What is the eigenvalue?